# How do I center, change the color and font of this string?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't know the first thing about coding or development, so if somebody could just re-paste my code with the corrections included that would be incredibly helpful. I am adding a current date widget to my website, but have no ability to center it, change the font color to white or change the font at all. Could somebody help me?

Here is the code I'm using in full:

```js
let date = new Date();
let day = String(date.getDate());
let weekday = date.getDay();
let month = date.getMonth();
let year = String(date.getFullYear());
const monthNames = ["January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
const weekdays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
month = monthNames[month];
weekday = weekdays[weekday]
let fullDate = (weekday + " " + day + ", " + month + ", " + year);
document.write(fullDate);
```

Comment: At first, you throw `document.write` to the trashes, then read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents

Comment: Ah. Like I said, don't know the first thing about coding, just need this one snippet to work on a site. How would I convert the date snippet up there from document.write to what you're saying?

Comment: Which part of the page are you putting it on? It looks like you may benefit from a crash course in basic HTML, CSS & javascript: https://www.w3schools.com/html/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

Note I wrapped the script in a page load event

Change `document.body.innerHTML +=` to for example

`document.getElementById("myDateContainer").innerHTML =`

if you have somewhere else to put it

myDateContainer could be `<div id="myDateContainer"></div>` somewhere on your page

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Some title</title>
  <style>
    .date {
      display: table;
      margin: 0 auto;
      color: red;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      let date = new Date();
      let day = String(date.getDate());
      let weekday = date.getDay();
      let month = date.getMonth();
      let year = String(date.getFullYear());
      const monthNames = ["January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
      const weekdays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
      month = monthNames[month];
      weekday = weekdays[weekday]
      let fullDate = (weekday + " " + day + ", " + month + ", " + year);
      document.body.innerHTML += `<span class="date">${fullDate}</span>`;
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**For centering add ** your style tag following before "color:red"

```
  <style>
    .date {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
  </style>
```

### Your code eventually should look like this: thanks to @mplungjan

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Some title</title>
  <style>
    .date {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      color: red;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      let date = new Date();
      let day = String(date.getDate());
      let weekday = date.getDay();
      let month = date.getMonth();
      let year = String(date.getFullYear());
      const monthNames = ["January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
      const weekdays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
      month = monthNames[month];
      weekday = weekdays[weekday]
      let fullDate = (weekday + " " + day + ", " + month + ", " + year);
      document.body.innerHTML += `<span class="date">${fullDate}</span>`;
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).